# Clustering of Twitter Feeds

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, data-mining

I am new to clustering, just implemented a couple of algorithms before.
I need to cluster tweets according to their similarity.
One way is to use only hash tags, but I don't think it would be that informative. So complete tweets should be analyzed.

Moreover I was searching the web for the algorithms for clustering feeds.

One I encountered is TF-IDF. I want to know are there better algorithms which can be implemented in few hours and are better than TF-IDF.Also I would be intersetd in some informatics source about the clustering of twitter feeds.

PS: No. of tweets : 10^5

Comment: TF-IDF is not a clustering algorithm. It is a normalization / similarity measure.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yeah, I just read it sorry. Is TF-IDF suitable for tweets purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure how well it works. Tweets are messy, the worst data set you can find... but well, garbage-in-garbage-out: maybe TF-IDF actually works as good as any other measure on garbage.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse For the purpose being, is the use of hierarchical clustering algorithm suitable as no. of clusters is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anony Mousse pointed out in his comment above, TF/IDF is only a normalization measure to make sure words that are overly popular among all documents don't gain too much important.

For data preparation, I'd recommend reading [this](http://css.dzone.com/articles/machine-learning-text-feature) and the second part of it too (linked via the above link), if you haven't already done so. It is very important to get a vector of numbers from each tweet. In general, in machine learning, it is important to get a feature vector because that way, you can apply mathematical algorithms to your data then.

Now that you have a feature vector for each tweet in your collection, things get a bit simple. There are two clustering algorithms that come to my mind that you can whip up in a couple of hours each, with maybe extensive testing taking a weekend.

- K-Means Clustering
- Hierarchical Clustering With Single Linkage

With 100,000 tweets only, you should actually be able to implement these algorithms on a single computer (i.e. this is not big data -- no need for cluster computing), using your favorite language (C++, Java, Python, MATLAB, etc.). Personally, I think it's easier to implement K-Means Clustering (which I have done before) compared to Hierarchical Clustering (which I have also done before).

**EDIT:** Please follow the below comments only if you have labeled training data, i.e. you have tweets say, with labeled sentiments (happy-user, ok-ok, bad product, angry-user, abusive-user) and the question you want to answer is: Given a new tweet, what is it's sentiment?

Here is one very good resource you should look at, to get a better understanding of K-Nearest Neighbors:

- [Laszlo Kozma's Slides](http://www.lkozma.net/knn2.pdf)

In general, for the other two algorithms, there are ample resources, with Wikipedia articles the best way to start. Personally, I feel K-Nearest Neighbors (shorthand k-NN) is the easiest of the three to implement and will give you quick results.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question i.e. what do you suggest about no. of clusters. As no. of clusters is unknown so how can I proceed to apply k mean clustering?

Comment: What *is* **k-nearest neighbors clustering???** I have not seen a publication that does this... most of the time, people either mean k-means, or kNN *classification* (as in the PDF you linked), *not clustering* ...

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Finding number of clusters is an active area of research itself. Try looking up on the "Elbow method" or check out the k-means++ algorithm. Personally, I think the "Elbow method" is quick and easy to implement.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You are right. I got ahead of myself. At some point while writing the post, I started thinking about classification, and k-NN came to mind naturally. k-NN is not an unsupervised learning algorithm. I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: @OP: Just to give you more insight on the "Elbow method": What you do is basically vary the number of clusters from 1 to N/2 (N = #data points). For each run, you calculate the F-statistic, and pick the k where there is a drastic drop in the slope of the % variance vs. #clusters graph. 

Issue: You may not get an accurate guess at the exact number of clusters you should use, since identifying this "elbow" is a subjective matter. But you get a pretty close ballpark figure for the value of k.
Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set#The_Elbow_Method

Comment: @nishant kelkar ok. If you have any experience on twitter data, can you suggest me to go through TF-IDF on every keyword of tweet or use hash tags only?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja It all depends on how much time you have to implement :)

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I don't have extensive experience with tweet data, but I can give some suggestions. It all depends on what you want to implement and how much time you have to do it:)

If you have a weekend to spend on this, I'd say go with parsing the tweet content. It's much messier (spelling mistakes, concatenated words, etc.) but you can readily find libraries online that take care of such issues. Stop word and punctuation removal and stemming should be easy. The difference between using tweet data vs. hashtags is only in the initial data cleansing